# No access to smb shares on NAS after win10 local user certificate expires

Tags: windows-10, certificate, smb

So Today, I attempted to access my NAS over SMB (`\\files`) on my network workgroup. The window hung for a moment, and a dialog I've never seen before when connecting to a share, with the title "Select Certificate" popped up. ultimately, I'm unable to access my shares from this box.

[image: Select Certificate window]

I can see that a certificate windows registered for my local user has expired.
it was issued by me to me, the very definition of self-signed.
The certificate has no trusted root certificate (not surprising).
Windows tells me I have a private key associated with this certificate.

I did not knowingly create a certificate, and I've never known SMB to just fail every year just because a cert expired (or really even to require one at all, if you are not on a domain).

A reboot didn't clear the issue, and I'm having difficulties finding information on generating a suitable replacement.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It appears I can get to shares using the FQDN, without any request for a certificate. DNS resolution works as well for hostnames as fullnames on my LAN, so I'm thinking something has remembered that destination, and needs to be flushed. any ideas what?

Comment: What are the Extended Key Usages of that certificate?

Comment: @user1686, ok I retract my last comment, I do see the cert in Certmgr, under the Personal keystore. It has no details on extended usages in the cert itself, and  the certificates purposes are all checked.

Comment: What is the NAS? Does it use Linux and Samba ?

Comment: its a Synology, so yes, linux and samba (DSM is up to date). I've set its min SMB spec to v2 amd max as v3. the users involved can login to the webportal, or access the shares via hostname from another workstation.

Comment: Are the IP of the NAS and client on the same subnet? Are they in a domain? Do you have some idea of what changed in the network that day or the day before?

Comment: its all on the same /24 subnet. the only thing I can identify that occurred on the 19th was that the certificate in question expired. it looks like it was generated 1 year prior, on 4/18/2020.  I am rather surprised that a something is requiring a cert for connection. Samba usually handles this kind of thing with username/password via PAM.  that it only does it for hostname lookup's, and only on this one workstation, it really seems like the settings are being preserved in a cache per destination URL, but I've no idea what cache that might be/

Comment: Try to delete this login in *Control Panel > User accounts > Manage your credentials* (check both by IP and name `files` and inside both Windows Credentials and Web Credentials), reboot, then login again to `\\files`.

Comment: @harrymc, your advice about Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your Credentials was indeed the trick I needed. Sorry for the delay in responding, Work has been such that I've been reluctant to reboot this week. Deleting the credentials and rebooting did restore my ability to navigate to the server by hostname. Please post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankThomas: Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Windows forget a stored login :

- Run *Control Panel > User accounts*
- Click "Manage your credentials"
- Find the login (identified by IP or its name `files`)
- Look inside both Windows Credentials and Web Credentials
- When found, click the down-arrow to the right of the credential
- Click "Remove" to delete
- Reboot
- Login again to `\\files`.

Comment: Great find, thanks again!